# How do I publish my Monogame game?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, monogame

Back then when I had Visual Studio 2011 installed, there was a "ClickOnce deployment" option in the project properties window that created self-extracting installation packages that also verified application dependencies (DirectX, ...). I have updated to VS2012 and switched to Monogame due to Microsoft cancelling any further XNA development. That also caused the "ClickOnce" deployment tab to be gone. Nobody I send the Release directory to (it includes some but apparently not all required libraries) can't get the game started - it always crashes, usually due to lack of some OpenAL DLL. Could you provide me with links and/or instructions on Monogame apps deployment/publishing? I've already tried Google but maybe I've overseen something.

I'm targetting Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article while googling for "Monogame Required Dlls":

http://xnameetingpoint.weebly.com/monogameintro.html

Basically, besides the assemblies in your Release folder the user would need to have OpenGL drivers installed.